Romantic comedy with a fake engagement
There is this film where someone, which I can't remember his name, meets his best friend or something while thinking of getting engaged and asks her to pretend to be his fiancee just for his grandother to be happy for him, I think. She agreed and they informed his family and get to move to their own apartment. Pretty quickly they fall for each other. 
It's probably from 2000-2010. Can't remember any possible actors. The film is American. I can't remember the name of it, please help.

Approximate year? Possible actors (or what they looked like)? Was it American? Where did you see it?

Probably 2000-2010, I think. Cant remember any possible acors. The film is American.

Thanks. Are you 100% sure it's to please his grandmother, BTW?

Based on the Grandmother part, it's likely Hitched for the Holidays (2012) http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2256703/ but I don't think they move into their own apartment. But man, Fake Wedding movies are common as hell, and your description is pretty generic.

@cde And they're not really friends, he finds her through an online ad. There's also One Small Hitch where they are friends but it's to please his dying father.

@Walt best friend or something.

You are a genius!! this is the one! 'one small hitch', this is the movie I'm trying to find in almost a month, really. Thank you so much, youve been very much helpful :)
